# split carbs, proteins, fruits for each meal or combined all in one meal

Tags: bellyfat

which is better option in below to reduce body fat

1)morning - 80 % protein , afternoon - 80 % carbohydrates , evening - handfull of nuts & eating only fruits at dinner.

2)taking carbs, proteins , fats & fruits for breakfast, lunch, dinner ?

Comment: Do you want to compete on stage or are you an actor in a movie? Someone that has reason to just quickly lose some weight? If you don't earn money with your body directly: Whatever you can keep up for the rest of your life. I personally prefer what tastes good and prevents hunger. But every person is different. If you think you can do either option for the rest of your life, go with it. You gained too much weight because you didn't eat right. If you've lost your weight after doing either option, do you want to go right back to gaining it again by eating as before or what is your plan?

Comment: @Raditz_35 thanks, don't know about future, but currently i badly wanted to reduce belly fat & have to gain muscles so i am waiting to clear the belly fat, so i am ready to go any level to achieve this, in future it depends on some factors that whether i ll continue the strict diet or i may satisfy my taste buds.....

Comment: If you are ready "to go any level", are you even ready to be patient and do this one right? People want fast results and are ready to put insane stress on themselves to achieve this. This isn't long term thinking. They gain the weight right away after they've achieved some goal or had enough because nobody can sustain that for years and decades. You can lose all your belly fat without crazy restrictions while satisfying your taste buds and having as many meals as you like, you just have to learn that stuff first.

Comment: @Raditz_35 that's right.... i completely agree : `nobody can sustain that for years and decades`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the underlying theory is absolutely true *(calories in vs calories out)*

---

It's so frustrating to see people all the time trying to lose weight.   The approach while well intended is backwards.

It's like running out of gas and Triple-A informing you that when you burn more gas than you've put in your tank your car doesn't run.

There's SO MUCH more to it than that.  How fast you accelerate, break, oil levels, tire pressure, the area (rural vs city) and on and on.......

Instead of learning about your body and the whys behind what you’re doing. Many people will hire a nutritionist to "tell them what to do".

Weight loss is in a lot of ways counter-intuitive.  At the extremes it's obvious *(eating an entire pie is worse than eating a few apples)*.

The middle ground, which is less obvious such as the types of foods, combinations of macronutrients, frequency, sizing and timing (etc.) will come as you learn....

Your body is incredibility adaptive. Restricting and starving yourself is the perfect way to teach your body to hold on to all the fat it can as it never knows when the next meal is coming.  Conservation and efficiency becomes your bodies plan.

The act itself of counting calories implicitly implies temporary.  Are you going to meticulously count calories for the rest of your life?

It incredibly inaccurate -- so if you spend the day measuring each meal and tracking calories and following it to a T the reported calories for many foods have been consistently found to be misreported, based on calorimeter data that's 1/2 a century old.

Give yourself "outs" foods there's literally no limit on . Or allow yourself to eat all the chocolate you want, it just has to be covered in mustard or whatever..

---

### UPDATE

In its simplest terms, yes, a “calorie deficit” is the only way to lose fat. It’s more insightful for me to tell you to become a millionaire you need to deposit $10,000 - 100 times.  Calories can’t be linearly measured like that.

Also, yes you can definitely put on “fat” eating too much of anything…. Vegetables and fruits included

I’m saying allow yourself more “wiggle room” as it’s MUCH harder to overconsume healthy food (that are typically higher in water content, less processed and require more energy to digest).

Even something calorie dense like almonds, not that you should make plans to “binge eat almonds” (it’s tough to even do so) but if you want them that bad, then you can them.

Or say you have lunch daily at noon, decide to start drinking 20oz of water at 11:30.  You’ll eat less (and you can carry this practice over to other times you tend to over eat).

Bottom line is restrictive does not work, some days you may eat more calories than you consume, that’s ok.   Adding the boringly painful task of calorie counting on top of restrictive eating (aka dieting) does not work long term.

Slowly learn about healthy eating and living and swap unhealthy foods with healthier alternatives.

Comment: thanks for nice explaination.....  i heard if we eat too much fruits [ 500 gms or 18 ounce] at a time , than it will increase insulin level & produce more fat in body.... so is the `calorie defict` is the ony reason to reduce fat ?

Comment: I think I've kind of gone full circle with my understanding of nutrition. I went from thinking "eat less, move more" to reading about nutrition and worrying about nutrient timing, meal consistency, gut health, insulin spikes, insulin resistance, magnesium deficiency, the DHA content of the fish oil I take, etc, etc, etc, right back around to realising that for most people, they get paralysed by all the information and just need someone to give them a few basics to stick to.

Comment: "need a few basics to stick to" -- yes absolutely!  It's not that hyper-focusing on every tiny aspect of your diet doesn't have it's place or wouldn't work per se.  It's just not practical or realistic.  Consistency, gradual learning and patience is all it takes.

Answer (score 1):

3) The one that adds up to the least calories.

As I mentioned [in another answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/36305/20219), the better option is the one you can stick to as pertains to your lifestyle, and results in a total caloric intake low enough to put you under your daily energy expenditure.

Unless you're at figure athlete level body composition, you probably don't need to overthink individual meal make up to this degree.

Comment: thanks, i heard if we eat too much fruits [ 500 gms or 18 ounce] at a time , than it will increase insulin level & produce more fat in body.... so is the `calorie defict` is the ony reason to reduce fat ?

Comment: As Mike mentioned in the other answer, it is actually more complex than that, but most people get too caught up with the micro and ignore the macro; by which I mean most people worry about taking extra ice in their drink so their body burns more calories heating it up, but ignore the fact they've just ordered extra bacon with their full English breakfast (I've seen someone do that)

Comment: well, as per your suggestion i will try to be strict with both macro & micro things :)